# Select all but the data based on search

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a little problem with select all, I copied the code from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2ay62?file=src/template-header-footer-example.component.html
. but I want to make select all based on the value in search.

for example, I have data 5 [A, BA, C, D, E] and I search for only the letter A, then the data will appear [A, BA] and when I click select all, only data [A, BA] will be selected , not all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an output event in ng-select called `search`. You can use that to filter data

You can do following changes in your ts and html
I have added one more property to class named `activePeople` which will store filtered data.

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'template-header-footer-example',
    templateUrl: './template-header-footer-example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./template-header-footer-example.component.scss']
})
export class TemplateHeaderFooterExampleComponent implements OnInit {

people = [];
selectedPeople = [];

activePeople = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getPeople().subscribe(items => {
        this.people = items;
        this.activePeople = items;
    });
}

selectAll() {
    this.selectedPeople = this.activePeople.map(x => x.name);
}

unselectAll() {
    this.selectedPeople = [];
}

onSearch(event) {
  this.activePeople = event.items;
}

}
```

HTML

```
<ng-select
[multiple]="true"
[items]="people"
[(ngModel)]="selectedPeople"
placeholder="Select people"
bindLabel="name"
bindValue="name"
(search)="onSearch($event)">
```

You can find more such events on
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/demo/app/examples/output-events-example/output-events-example.component.html